# Include files in an FSX file?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, f#-scripting

I use F# as a scripting language with FSI.  Is there a way to include another fsx file in my script?  I want to be able to break my scripts into multiple files for larger tasks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you should be able to use the `#load` directive to do what you want.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx.

Comment: Hmm, although, it just seems to run the file.  I can't call functions that are in the file.

Comment: @Avoidiam are you referencing the module name?  `ModuleName.someFunction()`

Comment: Try wrapping the script in a module, and do a Open modulename after #load. This works for me.